# window.onbeforeunload confirmation if submit not clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on a quiz. The page can't be closed before submitting the form, otherwise all data will be lost. This can be done using:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Are you sure?"
}
```

But what if I don't want to trigger this alert if user clicked on "Submit"? I tried the code below but it doesn't work at all - it doesn't show the alert even if window is being closed.

```
var clicked_submit = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#submit-button').click(function () {
          clicked_submit = true;
      });

      window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          if (clicked_submit){

          } else {
              return 'Are you sure?'
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: `False !== false` and `True !== true`, Also showing the message from the handler is browser dependent, some browsers ignore it.

Comment: instead of if else, you can simplay do if not: if(! ... also, you can override window.onbeforeunload=null; wich makes your code easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to just return the function without any value.

```
var clicked_submit = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#submit-button').click(function () {
          clicked_submit = true;
      });
      window.onbeforeunload = function () {
         if (clicked_submit){
             return; // equal to return undefined;
         } else {
             return 'Are you sure?'
         }
     }
});
```

---

A cleaner solution would be, to simply set the `window.onbeforeunload` to `null`.

```
var clicked_submit = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#submit-button').click(function () {
          clicked_submit = true;
      });
      if(!clicked_submit) {
          window.onbeforeunload = function () {
              return 'Are you sure?'
          }
      } else {
          window.onbeforeunload = null;
      }
});
```

Comment: It was my fault - False, True is in Python. Thanks